# Chef API getting 401 Unauthorized error chef

Tags: api, chef-infra

Always getting 401 unauthorized error when I am trying to get the response from Chef API . I am giving the correct header values for Basic Authentication and Accept. I am trying to get the response with the help of Java Rest Template. Could you please anyone help on this..

Answer (score 0):

Chef doesn't use Basic auth for API access so not sure what you think you're setting that to. https://docs.chef.io/auth.html#authentication-headers shows the official authentication spec. I would recommend using jclouds-chef for API access from Java, though unfortunately its docs are rather sparse.